# RxJS operator that doesn't emit to inner observable again until its completed

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm looking for an operator similar to `switchMap`, but instead of cancelling the previous inner observable, I want it to wait for its inner observable to complete before emitting to it a second time.

A common use case would be a user rapidly clicking on a button, piped to a HTTP request, that is then forwarded for display, like so:

`click$.pipe(switchMap(() => this.http.get("/something"))).subscribe(res => //);`

This would cancel the http request each time the user clicks on the button. Instead, I want to ignore the button click until the inner observable has completed, only then emitting a second time to it, and so on.

Is there an operator for this use case or a simple assembly of operators? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check [exhaustMap](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-exhaustMap). It seems completely fitting you needs.

> exhaustMap ignores every new projected Observable
>   if the previous projected Observable has not yet completed. Once that
>   one completes, it will accept and flatten the next projected
>   Observable and repeat this process.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using the exhaustMap operator.

```js
var clicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.querySelector("button"), 'click');
var result = clicks.exhaustMap((ev) => {
  ev.target.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  
return Rx.Observable.interval(5000).take(1)
  .do(() => ev.target.removeAttribute("disabled"));
  
});
result.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/dileren/edit?js,console,output)